# select div which has a span child element with certain attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to select a div based on the presence of a span element that has an attribute.

```
<div>
   <a>blabla</a>
   <p>blabla></p>
   <span data-stackoverflow="hello"></span>
   <img>blabla</img>
</div>
```

How do i do that?

How is this question the same as the question this question's supposed to be a duplicate of?
That question is about elements that hold certain attributes on which the elements are selected.

I want to be able to select a DIV based on a CHILD SPAN!! that has an attribute!!

***edit***

```
$( "div" ).has( 'span[data-stackoverflow="' + somevalue+ '"]' ).show();
```

This one workes for me however in some occasions it affects other div's as well.

Comment: I agree, your question is slightly different. Anyway, use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) on a search for divs using the method in the duplicate or use the method in the marked duplicate and call [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) on the match(es)

Comment: Thanks for that but it's not clear to me how then to select based on the value that the attribute holds.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('span').data('stackoverflow') == 'hello';
}).show();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZUHaU/)**